# How can i catch event when iframe starts loading

Tags: javascript, iframe

For example, user clicked link in iframe and i want in `parent.html` to show spinner. And i have cross domain iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind the click event of any element from the iframe to an event handler in the parent.
Using jquery:

UPDATE:

suppose in the parent you have the following function:

```
var clickHandler = function() {
    alert('Link in iframe clicked');
}
```

and your iframe contains a link with the class "LinkInIframe", just do this in the iframe:

```
$('a.LinkInIframe').click(function(e) {
    parent.clickHandler()
};
```

Comment: it'll be ok if iframe loads from the same domain, but i have different domains

Comment: oh, then i think you're out of luck. You can't access the inner content of an iframe it it sits on a different domain. It's a security measure.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work when link doesn't redirect or when the redirection comes out of javascript.